# How would I add a scroll bar into this macro in exel with the use of VBA microsoft

Tags: vba

[How would I make this scrollbar work? To make the items in the macro scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q7uG.jpg)

[image: Excel vba User Form Scroll Bar]

Comment: Theres an image here but im not sure if it will show up.

Comment: The scrollbar should work by default if you actually launch the userform.

Comment: Make the form larger!  You shouldn't be asking your users to scroll around your form when there's no need...

Comment: Did you insert a scroll bar control, or set the Userform Scrollbars Property, to show scroll bars? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the Form's Scroll Bar Property, and placing a Scroll Bar Control on a Form, are not the same thing.

If properly enabled, the Form's built-in Scroll Bars, should work automatically.

A Scroll Bar Control on the other hand, needs a Control Source. i.e. a Cell reference, or an Event, that you can call vba functions with, like "Private Sub Scrollbar_Change()".

**Form Scroll Bars**

[image: Scrollbars Property]

**Scroll Bar Control**

[image]